# Deriving Show instance with color output

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to derive a show instance with color output?

```
data MyData = MyData {red :: String}

instance Show MyData where ...
```

The idea is that whenever I print a variable of type MyData it will print in red(with ansi-terminal package for color output for example)

Comment: There is no way to automatically derive something like that, and in any case I would _highly_ recommend against this, because ansi-terminal is not fully cross platform.  It would be a nice feature until you try to give your code to someone else who is running a different OS.

Comment: From [the docs on `Show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show): "The result of show is a syntactically correct Haskell expression...". So it's a bad idea.

Comment: Nikita: the quotation is from the derived instance part, and it's not the case here. Though, it's starts with: "Conversion of values to readable Strings". We can argue about the readability of terminal-formatted strings.

Comment: You probably want the [ansi-terminal pretty print](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-wl-pprint) library. @Nicolas, it's considered best practice to ensure that read . show == id.

Comment: @acomar Great! This seems to be an even better alternative